# How do I setup Asterisk SIP Registration with Proxy and STUN Server?

Tags: linux, asterisk

I have register my SIP Account as follow:

```
SIP-server
User:           XXXXXXXXXX
Password:       YYYYYYYYYY

registrar:      registrar.mysip.com
domain realm:   mysip.com
SIP-port:       5060
STUN server:    stun.mysip.com
STUN port:      3478
proxy server    proxy.mysip.com
```

Registration entry in `/etc/asterisk/sip.conf`

```
register => XXXXXXXXXX@YYYYYYYYYY@registrar.mysip.com:5060/XXXXXXXXXX
```

How do I setup Proxy and STUN Server configuration in `sip.conf` file.

I have restarted asterisk and reload sip details.

```
sip reload

sip show registry
```

I got following:

```
NOTICE[9143]: chan_sip.c:15170 sip_reg_timeout:    -- Registration for 'XXXXXXXXXX@proxy.mysip.com' timed out, trying again (Attempt #48)


NOTICE[963]: chan_sip.c:15208 transmit_register: Strange, trying to register XXXXXXXXXX@proxy.mysip.com when registration already pending
```

Comment: Configuration of a VoIP platform seems rather off-topic here.

Comment: I have already setting up all those things, Only required How to add proxy details in sip.conf file or somewhere else in Linux?

Comment: Sure, but this is a programming Q/A site. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Asterisk is also Programming language. Please let me know where should I put.

Comment: Asterisk is definitely **not** a programming language, it's a VoIP software. Questions like this are more appropriate in [su] (and maybe [sf]), but you should check help center to make sure it's on-topic before asking on any Stack Exchange network site.

Answer (score 1):

I got answer by self research.

Issue from the SIP Service provider, they block my IP Addresses for that I am unable to connect.